# Интеграция мобильного приложения с онлайн-чатом и Битрикс24

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, битрикс24

Задача: нужно интегрировать внутри мобильного приложения (IOS, Android) онлайн-чат. Онлайн-чат нужен, чтобы пользователь мог общаться с менеджером компании. Менеджер работает в Битрикс24 в коробке.

Вопрос: есть ли готовые решения данной задачи? Если нет, то существует ли у Битрикс24 API для решения моей задачи?